# What is optical network coding? which techniques are there?

Tags: network, fiber, passive-optical-network

in optical network, what is network coding and which techniques are? is modulation a techniques of network coding?

Comment: Has any answer solved your question? Then please accept it or your question will keep popping up here forever. Please also consider voting for useful answers.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you mean *line* encoding, Ethernet uses various schemes. Line code is necessary on single serial connections for clock recovery and run length limitations.

- 10BASE-F uses Manchester code
- 100BASE-X uses 4b5b (from FDDI)
- 1000BASE-X uses 8b10b
- 10GBASE-R and faster use 64b66b
- PHYs with 50G lanes use additional PAM-4 to reduce the symbol rate

Comment: And then if you really want to blow your mind there is Coherent optical............

Comment: @PeterGreen I don't think we need to dive into the whole depths of optical signaling here. ;-)